# Get list of all subcollections firestore in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection called businesses which has a subcollection called candidates. How do I get all candidates collections for all businesses collections using angular. In my service I have the below function to achieve this but its return what I want

```
getAllCandidates(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.firestore.collection('businesses').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((businesses) => {
        return businesses.map((business) => {
          const businessId = business.payload.doc.id;
          const candidatesRef = this.firestore.collection(
            `businesses/${businessId}/candidates`
          );

          return candidatesRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map((candidates) => {
              return {
                businessId: businessId,
                candidates: candidates.map((candidate) => candidate.payload.doc.data()),
              };
            })
          );
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's not possible to list collections and subcollections using the web and mobile SDKs.  If your application depends on this, you should change your structure to represent these lists of things as documents or array elements that can be queried.  Collections and documents don't really operate like folders and files in a filesystem.

Comment: I am new to firebase, I took over a project from another developer. The structure was already there and I am trying to implement a feature for the client

Comment: Then you'll need to find another way to add or modify enough data to this project to make it work as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get all `candidates` [sub]collections for all `businesses` collections

Since you know the name of the subcollections (i.e. `candidates`) you can use a [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query): “A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID”.

The following code should do the trick (untested):

```
getAllCandidates(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.firestore.collectionGroup('candidates').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((candidates) => {...}))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up using valueChanges()

getAllCandidates(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.firestore.collectionGroup('candidates').valueChanges();
  }